# select the value of an xml attribute of an element if value of another attribute matches with value stored in a variable using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have below sample configuration. I have an xsl in which I have space seperated scope(getAccoutInfo getCustomerInfo) stored in variable 'scope', what you see below inside scope element as an individual input attribute. I am tokenizing them using str:tokenize

```
<scopes>
     <scope input="getAccountInfo" output="Account_Information"/>
     <scope input="getCustomerInfo" output="Customer_Information"/>
</scopes>

    <xsl:variable name="scopes" select="str:tokenize($scope, ' ')"/>
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>
   <font size="2" style="font-family:verdana">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$scopes[position()]"/>
   </font>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to print the values of corresponding 'output' attribute of an 'input' attribute as seen in above config as bullet points, using "apply-templates" to an individual token. The template is copied below.

```
<xsl:template match="token">
    <xsl:if test="$scopeMapping/*[local-name()='scopes']/*[local-name()='scope']/@*[local-name()='input']/text() = normalize-space(.)">

        <xsl:value-of select="$scopeMapping/*[local-name()='scopes']/*[local-name()='scope']/@*[local-name()='output']/text()"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But looks like the xsl code is not working for me. Can someone point out what is wrong and point in right direction?

Comment: Can you show the output you are expecting in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TimC Output should look like as below with bullet points: 
• Account_Information 
• Customer_Information–

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to select the `scope` elements whose `input` attribute appears in the tokenized `scopes` variable, then this simple expression should do the trick....

```
<xsl:for-each select="//scopes/scope[@input = $scopes]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                extension-element-prefixes="str">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="scope" select="'getCustomerInfo getAccountInfo'" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="scopes" select="str:tokenize($scope, ' ')"/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="//scopes/scope[@input = $scopes]">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@output" />
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input

```
<scopes>
     <scope input="getAccountInfo" output="Account_Information"/>
     <scope input="getCustomerInfo" output="Customer_Information"/>
</scopes>
```

The following is output:

```
<ul>
<li>Account_Information</li>
<li>Customer_Information</li>
</ul>
```